# cisco openconnect disconnect every 5 minutes

Tags: cisco, disconnect

Recently I installed Ubuntu (Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS) and I installed openconnect server I am faced with one problem. When I connect to my server with the cisco any connect app from my iphone or any connect software in windows 10 , my connection is disconnecting every 5 minutes.
Does anyone have a solution to how can I solve this issue?
I installed with below commands :

> > > Build docker image:
> > > docker build -t ocserv https://github.com/iw4p/OpenConnect-Cisco-AnyConnect-VPN-Server-OneKey-ocserv.git

> > > Run docker container:
> > > docker run --name ocserv --privileged -p 443:443 -p 443:443/udp -d ocserv

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu in a Docker Container? It does not say that in the question but the commands you show imply that.

Comment: yes it is running with docker , but my server disconnect every 5 min !

Comment: Please update the question and add this important missing info. Use the the edit command to add the info.

Comment: i just installed openconnect with docker , my question is how i can do to stop disconnect open connect every 5 min,  i tested on laptop (windows 10) and android phone and iphone , all are same and disconnect every 5 min , i dont know which code should be stop this disconnect and reconnect process